# Trying to check one 2d char array for keywords in a second 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare, keyword-search

I'm trying to compare one text file, in this case a resume, with another file with a series of keywords in it. I've turned the files into 2d arrays, and am trying to check the resume for the keywords, but it looks like it's counting the characters instead of the words. I'm not sure how to go about just counting the words here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I'm trying to work with:

```
        for (x = 0; x < 500; x++) {//starts and the first char of the resume, then moves to the next
            for (z = 0; z < 30; z++) {//runs through the first word
                if (resumeArray[x][z] == keywordArray[y][z]) {//if the word matches the keyword, then it's true
                    if(resumeArray[x][0] == keywordArray[y][0]){
                        if(resumeArray[x][z] == ' ')
                        keywordCount++;//if it's a true statement, then increase the keyword count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        y++;//move on to the next keyword
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should rewrite it like this:

```
for (x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
        bool res = true;
        for (z = 0; z < 30; z++) {
            if (resumeArray[x][z] != keywordArray[y][z]) {
                res = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(res) keywordCount++;
    }
```

In above code, I used `res` to check if has any different in your array with keyword array. If had any difference, there is no need to check more and set `res` be `false` and it will not increase `keywordCount`.

Comment: That's closer than what I had been getting, but it looks like it's still counting characters instead of the full words.

Comment: Could you give your sample data? in this case, each row of resumeArray has to match with keywordArray! Actually, you can base on this to detect your keyword.

Comment: The resume I'm using is a pretty long .txt file. Really, any series of words in an array should work, as long as the other array has some keywords to look for.

Comment: my code will work with the array input like this ["abc 123", "bcd 213"] and your key is "abc 123". The keywordCount will be 1.